# Is it possible to go back and change the last input you entered into a command prompt questionnaire?

Tags: shell, unix, npm, terminal, command-prompt

**If I accidentally entered a typo into a command prompt questionnaire, is there a way to go backwards and edit that input?**

For example, when I run `npm init`, I'm given a bunch questions. If I accidentally write a typo in the `package name` field and press enter, the questionaire moves on to `version:`. Is there a way to quickly go back to `package name` and fix my typo?

[image]

My experience with the terminal and npm is limited, but I found out that you [cannot undo a command line](https://superuser.com/questions/195252/is-there-an-undo-command-on-the-unix-comand-line). However, I'm wonder if you CAN undo an answer to a *command prompt*, since this is a little different- The command hasn't really run yet until all the prompts are done.

```
Sat Apr 27 npm Dashie$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (npm) oops-typo
version: (1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An undo functionality like you are describing would have to be implemented by the developers of the cli tool you are using (in this case, npm).

I think the best I can offer as a means to fix your mistake on the command line, without having to open an editor and modify the package.json file from there, is to use the [json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json) npm package.

So in the particular case displayed in your question, you would keep going with the install and afterwards you could simply do:

```
$ npm i -g json
$ json -I -f package.json -e "this.name='your package name'"
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the workaround. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the package name in the package.json file created when you use init.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that. I’m just wondering if you can do it in terminal right after making the mistake. Though you can just edit the package.json file, I feel like there would be instances where a prompt comes up and changing your typo in terminal would be easier. Perhaps not with npm init, but any situation with a prompt.